# extract displaynames from a list of samaccountnames

Tags: powershell

I want to get an output like below. how can I do that ?

My script:

```
import-module activedirectory
Get-Content 'C:\Temp\Users.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser $_ -Properties DisplayName
} | Select-Object  samaccountname,DisplayName |
Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

My output :

```
"samaccountname","DisplayName"
"user01","John t"
"user02","Sandra M"
```

My desired output :

```
user01(John T);user02(Sandra M)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exporting to csv, which is in your script - you have to parse the output

```
#your script
import-module activedirectory
Get-Content 'C:\Temp\Users.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser $_ -Properties DisplayName
} | Select-Object  samaccountname,DisplayName |
Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\output.csv -NoTypeInformation

#parsing output
$csv = (Import-Csv "C:\Temp\output.csv")
[string]::Join(";",$($csv | % { "$($_.samaccountname)`($($_.DisplayName))"}))
```

This iterates through items, parses objects to desired format and then, using `[string]::Join()` (basically .NET's `string.Join()` method) it merges the output to single string.

The result is:
`user01(John t);user02(Sandra M)`

Comment: btw, I can't see Get-AdUser cmdlet

Comment: What do you mean by "can't see Get-AdUser cmdlet"? This script should go after what you did - it basically parses the csv output from your script to desired state :)

Comment: I edited my answer to use also your script. :)